# Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘ThisComponent’

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
inputOne :: GenerateState Description
inputOne = do
  g <- get
  let ifDesc False = ""
      ifDesc _ = "the function for inputs "
  return $ ifDesc $ "my_inputs" `elem` defList g
```

I'm trying to replace the "my_inputs" with a variable, and I absolutely need to use a new datatype for this.

```
class RenderChoices a where
    showChsChar :: a -> [Char]

data ThisComponent = GetInput 

instance RenderChoices ThisComponent where 
  showChsChar GetInput = "my_inputs"

inputOne :: GenerateState Description
inputOne = do
  g <- get
  let ifDesc False = ""
      ifDesc _ = "the function for inputs "
  return $ ifDesc $ GetInput `elem` defList g
```

Shouldn't showChsChar have turned the "my_inputs" into a [Char], so shouldn't `` return $ ifDesc $ GetInput `elem` defList g `` work like `` return $ ifDesc $ "my_inputs" `elem` defList g `` worked? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you please share the definition, and Monad instance, of your type `GenerateState`? (also the definition of `Description`)

Comment: I am puzzled by your question though because you ask "Shouldn't showChsChar have turned the "my_inputs" into a [Char]" and yet the quoted code never calls `showChsChar`

Comment: voting to close. Lacks debugging details.

Comment: You need to use ``return $ ifDesc $ showChsChar GetInput `elem` defList g``. That function won't be called automatically, you need to explicitly use it. However, the overall approach seems confusing to me -- I don't understand what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].